# Gradle sync error message

Tags: android

[image]

I've installed android studio but this type of error pop up

Answer (score 0):

This will surely solve your problem.
First of all check update for Studio if available update it.
Then,

```
Launching studio64.exe instead of the studio.exe(I've got a 64-bits machine).
Add/Change the following values in "studio64.exe.vmoptions":
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```